# High numerical precision floats with MySQL and the SQLAlchemy ORM

Tags: python, mysql, orm, sqlalchemy, floating-accuracy

I store some numbers in a MySQL using the ORM of SQLAlchemy. When I fetch them afterward, they are truncated such that only 6 significant digits are conserved, thus losing a lot of precision on my float numbers. I suppose there is an easy way to fix this but I can't find how. For example, the following code:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.pool import QueuePool
import sqlalchemy.ext.declarative as sad

Base    = sad.declarative_base()
Session = sa.orm.scoped_session(sa.orm.sessionmaker())

class Test(Base): 
    __tablename__   = "test"
    __table_args__  = {'mysql_engine':'InnoDB'}
    no      = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    x       = sa.Column(sa.Float)


a = 43210.123456789
b = 43210.0
print a, b, a - b

dbEngine = sa.create_engine("mysql://chore:BlockWork33!@localhost", poolclass=QueuePool, pool_size=20,  
                                 pool_timeout=180)              
Session.configure(bind=dbEngine)   
session = Session()            

dbEngine.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test")
dbEngine.execute("USE test")  
Base.metadata.create_all(dbEngine)   

try:
    session.add_all([Test(x=a), Test(x=b)])
    session.commit()
except:
    session.rollback()
    raise

[(a,), (b,)] = session.query(Test.x).all()
print a, b, a - b
```

produces

```
43210.1234568 43210.0 0.123456788999
43210.1 43210.0 0.0999999999985
```

and I would need a solution for it to produce

```
43210.1234568 43210.0 0.123456788999
43210.1234568 43210.0 0.123456788999
```

Comment: I'm not certain, not having used sqlalchemy, but per [the documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/types.html#sql-standard-types), I think you should be able to specify sa.types.Float(precision=[precision here]) instead of sa.Float.

Comment: @AMacK Yes I know. I tried it... or at least I thought I tried it. Actually, I tried sa.Float(Precision=32) which made no change at all. However, using sa.types.Float(precision=32), it does work... I guess it is not without reason that their is "Alchemy" in the name SQLAlchemy. If you put it in form of an answer (rather than a comment) I'll put it as the official answer.

Comment: Thanks much.
Huh, strange. Fun times.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per our discussion in the comments: `sa.types.Float(precision=[precision here])` instead of `sa.Float` allows you to specify precision; however, `sa.Float(Precision=32)` has no effect. See [the documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/types.html#sql-standard-types) for more information.

Comment: FWIW I was struggling with SQLAlchemy syntax. My project is in Flask (so using Flask SQLAlchemy). To get ```float``` in line here is the syntax that worked for me: 


```ColumnName=db.Column(db.Float(precision='3,2')) # db is part of the Flask operation```


The above '3,2' produced a (MySQL) field of ```XXX.YY```. Hope that helps someone out there as the docs are not as clear as I would like at times (Flask and SQLAlchemy).

Comment: Can you quote from the docs or be more specific where it says that the `sa.Float(Precision=32)` format has no effect?

Comment: @datamafia or anyone else, if you use alembic, do you see changes to float precision coming through in your migrations? If so, what does it look like?

Comment: @BrianPeterson 2 things. 1-, here is a copy from my migration ```sa.Column('ProductPrice', sa.Float(precision='3,2'), nullable=True),```. And 2-All alembic migrations must be reviewed with fine tooth comb and in general are in error. So the quoted line works, but I may have had to write it from scratch, like most Alembic migrations. Feel free to reach out direct for more info. In this example I am on MySQL.

Comment: IMO it's `(5,2)` for `xxx.yy`.

Comment: Supporting pnv's comment with more info: MySQL permits a nonstandard syntax: FLOAT(M,D) or REAL(M,D) or DOUBLE PRECISION(M,D). Here, “(M,D)” means than values can be stored with up to M digits in total, of which D digits may be after the decimal point. For example,

(that's excerpted from MySQL Reference Manual:  [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/floating-point-types.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/floating-point-types.html) )

Comment: How can one invoke this without establishing a class? Any thoughts?