# Floating number rounding on Database

Tags: python, dataframe, sqlalchemy, rounding

I have the following df:

```
df
          Process Commodity Direction  ratio  ratio-min
0      Coal plant      Coal        In   1.00        NaN
1      Coal plant      Elec       Out   0.40        NaN
2      Coal plant       CO2       Out   0.30        NaN
3   Lignite plant   Lignite        In   1.00        NaN
4   Lignite plant      Elec       Out   0.40        NaN
5   Lignite plant       CO2       Out   0.40        NaN
6       Gas plant       Gas        In   1.00        NaN
7       Gas plant      Elec       Out   0.60        NaN
8       Gas plant       CO2       Out   0.20        NaN
9   Biomass plant   Biomass        In   1.00        NaN
10  Biomass plant      Elec       Out   0.35        NaN
11  Biomass plant       CO2       Out   0.00        NaN
12      Wind park      Wind        In   1.00        NaN
13      Wind park      Elec       Out   1.00        NaN
14    Hydro plant     Hydro        In   1.00        NaN
15    Hydro plant      Elec       Out   1.00        NaN
16  Photovoltaics     Solar        In   1.00        NaN
17  Photovoltaics      Elec       Out   1.00        NaN
```

As you can see `ratio` values are floating numbers.

I am trying to send this dataframe to the databank using sqlalchemy.

Here I am setting up the table:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

table = sa.Table(table_name,
                 metadata,
                 sa.Column('index', sa.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False),
                 sa.Column('Process', sa.VARCHAR(50)),
                 sa.Column('Commodity', sa.VARCHAR(50)),
                 sa.Column('Direction', sa.VARCHAR(50)),
                 sa.Column('ratio', sa.Float(10)),
                 sa.Column('ratio-min', sa.Float(10)),
                 schema=schema_name)
```

Then I send the table to databank via: `df.to_sql(table_name, engine, schema=schema_name, if_exists='replace')`

Problem is when I check the databank all the values of `ratio` is somehow rounded. And following is what I am getting from the databank (it is also same rounded values in databank)

```
          Process Commodity Direction  ratio ratio-min
0      Coal plant      Coal        In    1.0      None
1      Coal plant      Elec       Out    0.0      None
2      Coal plant       CO2       Out    0.0      None
3   Lignite plant   Lignite        In    1.0      None
4   Lignite plant      Elec       Out    0.0      None
5   Lignite plant       CO2       Out    0.0      None
6       Gas plant       Gas        In    1.0      None
7       Gas plant      Elec       Out    1.0      None
8       Gas plant       CO2       Out    0.0      None
9   Biomass plant   Biomass        In    1.0      None
10  Biomass plant      Elec       Out    0.0      None
11  Biomass plant       CO2       Out    0.0      None
12      Wind park      Wind        In    1.0      None
13      Wind park      Elec       Out    1.0      None
14    Hydro plant     Hydro        In    1.0      None
15    Hydro plant      Elec       Out    1.0      None
16  Photovoltaics     Solar        In    1.0      None
17  Photovoltaics      Elec       Out    1.0      None
```

**How would I prevent `to_sql` to round my `ratio` values?**

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280905/high-numerical-precision-floats-with-mysql-and-the-sqlalchemy-orm

Comment: Answer to the question u mention says that I have to use `sa.types.Float` instead of `sa.Float`, and it does literally no difference :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work around this by specifying the data type of your column like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.types import Float
```

then add

```
dtype={'ratio': Float()}
```

to the arguments of `df.to_sql`:

```
df.to_sql(table_name, engine, schema=schema_name, if_exists='replace', dtype={'ratio': Float()})
```

The argument `dtype` is a dictionary which takes column names as keys and data types as values. This should prevent your `ratio` values from being rounded.